# db2 query: replacement for 'with'

Tags: db2, jasper-reports

Our code structure is something like this:

```
select
sampleA.columnA,
(select sampleB.columnA 
    from sampleB where sampleB.ColumnB = 'test1'),
(select sampleB.columnA 
    from sampleB where sampleB.ColumnC = 'test2')
from sampleA
join sampleB on sampleA.id = sampleB.id
where sampleA.columnB = 'test3'
```

What happens is.. if we run only the 
`select sampleB.columnA from sampleB where sampleB.ColumnB = 'test1'` 
then that returns us 27 results. 
Similarly it returns some other say 35 rows for 
`select sampleB.columnA from sampleB where sampleB.ColumnC = 'test2'`

But when we run the entire query, we get scalar error....

We are using DB2 and ultimately want to run this on Jasper.. and Jasper does not support 'with' any other way?

Comment: The keyword `With` is supported by JasperReports. I made several reports using `with`

Comment: could you share an example? As I am using jasper studio 6.3.0, and 'with' was marked in red... as soon as I removed the 'with' statement then the query ran fine

Comment: Sample: `WITH date_range AS
(SELECT
   add_months(TRUNC($P{period_start}, 'MM'), 1 * Level - 1) month,
   level
 FROM dual
 CONNECT BY level <= months_between($P{period_end}, $P{period_start}) + 1
),
    orders AS (SELECT TRUNC(orders.created_ts, 'MM') AS month
                 FROM orders)
SELECT trunc(d.month, 'MM') month
FROM date_range d, orders o
WHERE d.month = o.month
ORDER BY month`

Comment: Did you try to just ignore the warning? If the query is valid (you checked it) it should also works

Answer (score 0):

A subquery must return only one row, try this :

```
select sampleA.columnA,
(select sampleB.columnA from sampleB where sampleB.ColumnB = 'test1' FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY) as columnAtest1 ,
(select sampleB.columnA from sampleB where sampleB.ColumnC = 'test2' FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY) as columnAtest2
from sampleA 
join sampleB on sampleA.id = sampleB.id
where sampleA.columnB = 'test3'
```

or this

```
select sampleA.columnA,
Samplec.columnA as columnAtest1, Sampled.columnA as columnAtest2
from sampleA 
join sampleB on sampleA.id = sampleB.id
cross join (select sampleB.columnA from sampleB where sampleB.ColumnB = 'test1' FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY) Samplec
cross join (select sampleB.columnA from sampleB where sampleB.ColumnB = 'test2' FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY) Sampled
where sampleA.columnB = 'test3'
```